# Is there any detailed insight for iOS App like in Android?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, google-analytics-api

I notice there is no detailed insight on my app on iTunesConnect like android insight GooglePlay.

Is there any way to track user detail on every user install my app? I need more distinct information like, iOS version, phone provider, phone type, etc across installed app like in Android insight? does Google Analytics could do this?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.flurry.com is the one everyone that I know uses.

Comment: @Dex you should really write it as an answer giving a little more details about usage, registration and fees. That would be very cool.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of analytics providers around that cater for iOS. As you mentioned, Google Analytics (which is free) should do what you need. [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/) is a really nice provider, but is only free for a certain amount of data. I've also used [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com) in the past (also free), but I find their web interface to be quite clunky.

If you want to track sales and App Store reviews, I'd really recommend [AppFigures](http://www.appfigures.com). Great service (paid, but a low monthly cost and you can cancel whenever), which gives you great insight into who's downloading your apps.